# Bracket polynomial of a hopflink

Tags: knot-theory

When you are computing the bracket polynomial of the (for example) hopflink, why can you not smooth all the crossings in one go? Why do you have to only first start with one crossing?

For example in this paper http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2006/vol7-n1/paper6/v7n1-6pd.pdf

on page 4, where it is calculating the bracket polynomial of the hopflink, in the second line of the working for A, why doesnt the author just smooth the bottom crossing as well in that step?

Comment: How do you define the smoothing of several crossings at the same time?

Comment: I am looking at the colin adams book and he first positively smooths one of the crossings positively but he leaves the other one when he could also have smoothed it as well. He is left with a circle with another circle inside but if he had done what I said then there would be no circle inside.

Comment: Right, because how have you defined what smoothing two crossings simultaneously should do to the bracket?

Comment: (I have attached a paper to show what I mean.  What do you mean?

Comment: I mean you have a definition for what should happen when you remove one crossing. Do you have one that says what happens when you remove two (without requiring something about how those crossings are positioned relative to each other)?

Comment: No I dont think so. I know that you smooth the crossings positively but not sure why you would not do it to all of them.

Comment: You still have not explained what rule you would apply to the bracket when smoothing multiple crossings.

Comment: I have no idea sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can smooth all the crossings at once.  But keep in mind that each crossing is replaced by two smoothings, so the number of smoothed diagrams (disjoint circles with no crossings) doubles with each additional crossing.  For example, the Hopf link with $2$ crossings has $2^2 = 4$ smoothings.  The standard picture of the trefoil knot with $3$ crossings has $2^3 = 8$ smoothings.  (See page 4 of [this paper](http://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/papers/Categorification/Categorification.pdf) by Dror Bar Natan, but keep in mind that he uses different coefficients for the "0" and "1" smoothings of a crossing.)

Smoothing all the crossings at once is the *state-sum* approach, and it is very useful.  The challenge is to organize the $2^n$ diagrams (for a link with $n$ crossings) in a meaningful way.  You have to keep track of how many crossings were smoothed in the "0" vs. "1" way and attach polynomial coefficients accordingly.  It's sensible to think of the $0$s and $1$s as coordinates of the vertices of an $n$-dimensional hypercube.

Study the diagram in the linked paper, but try to attach powers of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ (rather than $1$ and $q$) for smoothings and powers of $-A^2 - A^{-2}$ (rather than $q + q^{-1}$) for loops.